# How to modify .ini file inside C:\Windows \

Tags: c#

I am working on an application that uses a .ini file that is located inside C:\Windows folder. I am following the code from microsoft to do the modification . Here is the link for that. It works perfectly fine for everything else other than the Windows folder. Is there any way around that? Here is the link if you are interested in the code. 
[Link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Reading-and-Writing-Values-85084b6a)

Please help. 
Thanks,

Comment: External links are likely to go bad over time.  Please include the relevant information in your question.

Comment: First, are you working on desktop app?

Comment: A program must ask for UAC elevation in order to modify files in C:\Windows.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2818776/17034

Comment: Yes i am working on a desktop app.